# two subjects connected by or \ subject verb agreement

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, disjunction

Has \ have the horse or the cattle been found ?

OR replacing subjects as :

Has \ have the cattle or horse been found ?

Which verb is correct (has or have) to begin with ?

---

**My question is different to the links you offered

These you linked to are known to any learner even the very beginner knows it

So which subject is the nearer to RO here ?**

**You can't answer it, so you closed.**

I Really supposed perhaps I find one author British or American mentioned such a rule , but sorrowfully I have not found even I searched at least 200 books or more.

I think the question pattern is incorrect and I suggest to use ( either --or )

Has \ have either the horse or the cattle been found ?

The only notices I found are these :

(Has, Have) either the boy or the girls reached the location?

Answer the question: No, neither the boy nor the girls have reached the location.

Which verb ( has or have ) is correct The author did not make it clear out of his notices And he is neither British nor American.

And let me announce it by a loud voice ( All flee when it becomes critical )

I am not a native speaker of the English language but perhaps I know more than the native themselves and at least I search and ask

This matter ( subject verb agreement ) in the interrogative sentences is hardly one can find a rule for it.

[image]

Comment: My question is different   So which  subject is the nearer to  RO here ?

Comment: The proximity rule, if you followed it, would demand *Has the horse or cattle been found yet* versus *Have the cattle or horse been found yet*. But in real-world use, you might find that people prefer a plural here. If you have a fussy editor, then you could just choose the second version that places the cattle before the horse, and nobody would complain.

Comment: Thank you   And let me announce it by a loud voice ( All flee when it becomes critical )

I am not a native speaker of the English language but perhaps I know more than the native themselves and at least I search and ask

This matter ( subject verb agreement ) in the interrogative sentences is hardly one can find a rule for it.

Comment: The proximity "rule" of disjunction is no different in questions than it is declarative sentences. But sometimes it works out to something that can sound weird to us, and so we avoid those by rewording them if we don't have to please some silly editor. It the real world, both versions can be found. Again, there is no difference whatsoever between interrogative and declarative sentences in this matter. Native speakers will do what they please, and editors may fuss at them if they get the chance, but it's not that important in the long run. Your book is confusing about this: Rule 6 seems wrong.

Comment: You didn't provide a link to the question which you say has been closed.

Comment: Ahmad - You seem to believe there's some kind of "idealised"  version of English which exists independently of its native speakers. But actually, English is defined by what native Anglophones say, not what prescriptive grammarians say we *should* say.

Answer (score 0):

The proximity rule, if you followed it, would demand *Has the horse or cattle been found yet* versus *Have the cattle or horse been found yet*. But in real-world use, you might find that people prefer a plural here. If you have a fussy editor, then you could just choose the second version that places the cattle before the horse, and nobody would complain.

The proximity "rule" of disjunction is no different in questions than it is declarative sentences. But sometimes it works out to something that can sound weird to us, and so we avoid those by re-wording them if we don't have to please some silly editor. It the real world, both versions can be found.

Again, **there is no difference whatsoever between interrogative and declarative sentences** in this matter. Native speakers will do what they please, and editors may fuss at them if they get the chance, but it's not that important in the long run.

Your book is confusing about this: Rule 6 as stated seems wrong. You don't "answer the question". All you do is have the verb agree grammatically with the number of the nearest noun phrase in the disjunction.

"Is Tom, or Dick, or Harry coming to dinner?"

Answer (score -2):

The answer  yes  Has the horse or the cattle been found ?

### OK but it is better to edit the question as
( Has\ have either the horse or the cattle been found ?
And the correct verb of course = has

I challenge you all, if one author native speaker or not native speaker mentioned a rule of subject verb agreement that works with interrogative sentences and especially when the sentence includes two subjects linked by or  not ( either - or \ neither nor )  and when you search online you can notice all say ( the verb should agree with the part of the subject that is closest to the verb )

Which verb  is it the auxiliary or the lexical ( main verb ) ?
No one has made it clear.

I surely know we go with the auxiliary, simply if we say or ask

( are there students ready for the exam) ?   Is there anyone here ?

I know all these, but if you notice all the examples using ( either --or \ neither nor )  in the statement sentences, the verb usually comes after nor \ or and agrees with the noun ( subject ) that is closer

Neither the cat nor the dogs are going outside.  \ Neither the cats nor the dog is going outside.

In the interrogative the verb ( auxiliary) is in the front position not like the examples of ( either or \ neither nor) **which all put in one rule. and here is the point = not precise rules**

So , I recommend a clear rule is to be added to all books of grammar and not leave it ambiguous at a half rule.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you  I added my own notices

Comment: Answers should be answers. They should not be more questions. They should not be discussions with other posters. They should give reasons or references or both to support them.